# Error when import a node_module on svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte, rollup, sapper

i have to create a module to use on my application, but when I import that in my major project i have this error

```
Error: Cannot find module '.../node_modules/Table/dist/index.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
```

I have not the folder dist/index.js, in the guide I followed I did not see that it was necessary to make the package, also in another project i did not have these problems. My version of node is v12.16.2

---

I update my rollup to build with `npm run dev`

Here there is my new rollup

```
import svelte from 'rollup-plugin-svelte';
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
    
const pkg = require('./package.json');
    
export default {
        input: 'src/Table.svelte',
        output: {
            file: `dist/bundle.js`,
            format: "iife"
        },
        plugins: [
            svelte(),
            resolve({ preferBuiltins: true, mainFields: ['browser'] })
        ],
        external: ['uuid', 'object-exporter']
};
```

But i have again this error

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:327
      throw err;
      ^

Error: Cannot find module '/../../node_modules/Table/dist/index.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
```

Comment: how are you importing the module ?

Comment: import Table from 'Table'

Comment: Seems that you define the `main` in `package.json` like `"main": "dist/index.js"` but `dist/index.js` doesn't exist. Have you forget to build your package before using it?

Comment: i update the first post to show the new error and new rollup

Comment: Are you using globally installed node.js or project level references?

Comment: global installed node, where i want to import the node_module is a sapper project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rollup config build your package in `dist/bundle.js`:

```js
output: {
    file: `dist/bundle.js`,
    format: "iife"
},
```

But you probably defined in your `package.json`:

```json
  "main": "dist/index.js",
```

But `dist/index.js` doesn't exits. Just replace it with `"main": "dist/bundle.js"`.

Comment: Where i have to put "main": "dist/bundle.js"?

Comment: @fr33js in the `package.json` file.

Comment: i fixed, now told me that: `uuid is not defined` that is a library used on my node_module

Comment: @fr33js Great but that isn't the original problem :) Please open a new question for this one and `validate` this one if it fixed your original issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64556839/dependecies-of-node-module-inside-another-node-module

Comment: I will have a look. Please also consider validate this answer or tell me what is missing.